# Lexicon group matching in text

Tags: r

I have lexical data like this:

```
C#
C++
Windows 7
Windows Azure
Programming
Programming C
```

I would like to group them into more general categories. Is there any option to make a software engineering term matching into a more abstract groups in R?

Example wherever:

```
C++
C#
Programming C
```

List them to C

the same with windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach using a few GitHub packages I maintain ... but  you'll need to tweak it to be more generalizable.

```
dat <- readLines(n = 6)
C#
C++
Windows 7
Windows Azure
Programming
Programming C

if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load_gh(
    "trinker/textshape", 
    "trinker/gofastr", 
    "trinker/termco",    
    "trinker/hclustext"
)

ds <- data_store(gsub("[^[:alpha:] ]", " ", dat), stopwords = c("programming", "program"))
myfit <- hierarchical_cluster(ds)
plot(myfit, 2)
ca <- assign_cluster(myfit, k = 2)

split(dat[as.numeric(names(ca))], ca)

## $`1`
## [1] "C#"            "C++"           "Programming C"
## 
## $`2`
## [1] "Windows 7"     "Windows Azure"
```